# using interface to get a Todo id OR JPA getOne method which faster

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to understand the best approach on which is faster on implementation to get a Todo instance or id.

```
 @Repository
    public interface TodoDao extends JpaRepository<Todo, Long> {
    TodoInterface getASingleApplication(Long id);
    }
    
    
    //inside the controller
    
    Todo todo = todoDao.getOne(id); //this gets an object including all the relationships of Todo class using jpa crud repository
```

from the above, I can do

```
print out >>> todo.getId(); //returns from jpa
    TodoInterface todoInterface = todoDao.getASingleApplication(id); //this returns just the id of Todo
    print out  >>>> todoInterface.getId();
```

Please which is the best practice

Comment: Did you inspect the SQL output? (Also, if you already _have_ the ID, why are you querying for it?)

Comment: I am comparing the two approaches on which is faster

Comment: What is faster is `print id`.